# Understanding variance in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, akka

I have following code:

```
 trait DestinationBinding[T <: Actor] {
def resolve(implicit context: ActorContext, manifest: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): ActorRef = {
  println(s"creating destination binding actor of:$name")
  context.actorOf(Props[T], name)
}

def name: String = manifest.runtimeClass.getSimpleName
}
```

That is basically just a simple way to create actors. And following some implementations.

```
case class BlackHoleBinding extends DestinationBinding[BlackHoleDeliveryAgent]
```

Where `BlackHoleDeliveryAgent` is an Actor

There are also some messages:

```
case class Delivery[T <: Actor](message: Any, binding: DestinationBinding[T])
```

Problem appears when I want to pattern match over those:

```
Note: com.elemica.erc.BlackHoleDeliveryAgent <: akka.actor.Actor (and BlackHoleBinding <:    DestinationBinding[BlackHoleDeliveryAgent]), but trait    DestinationBinding is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]     case Delivery(message, binding: BlackHoleBinding) => {
```

Comment: We really need to see more code, can you give us the entire match expression? Guessing based on what you have, it looks like you are trying to match a value of `Delivery[Actor]` against `Delivery[BlackHoleDeliveryAgent]`, which will always fail because `Delivery[BlackHoleDeliveryAgent]` isn't a subtype of `Delivery[Actor]`. If you did as it suggests, and declare T as +T, it would be subtype and matching would be possible.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it blows with another error will post it.

Answer (score 0):

Variance is always a bit tricky to deal with; the problem here is that you have the BlackHoleDeliveryAgent is a subclass of Actor but that doesn't mean that DestinationBinding[BlackHoleDeliveryAgent] is a subclass of DestinationBinding[Actor] and thus of any other DestinationBinding[T <: Actor]; this is because DestinationBinding is invariant on T.

If you make your DestinationBinding co-variant in T it will mean that DestinationBinding[T] will be a subclass of DestinationBinding[S] if T is a subclass of S (which is what you want in this case). You do this by defining the DestinationBinding as follows:

```
trait DestinationBinding[+T <: Actor] {... }
```

For the sake of knowledge, there is also a contra-variant annotation that will do the opposite, so that if T is a subclass of S DestiniationBinding[S] will be a subclass of T. This is done as follows:

```
trait DestinationBinding[-T <: Actor] { ... }
```